# How to get files by using index of List files in groovy

Tags: groovy

I got the List of all files by using but it give all files , I need specific files from list.

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

def dir = new File("path_to_parent_dir")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file
}

list.each {
  println it.path
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have, what you need, and where you're having troubles?

Answer (score 1):

The method `File.eachFileRecurse(FileType, Closure)` can only filter by `FileType`; the options being `FILES`, `DIRECTORIES`, and `ANY` (everything). Keep in mind this is file type in the *filesystem* sense, and has nothing to do with the file contents. For instance, an HTML document and a PNG image are both `FILES`.

If you want to filter by, say, the file extension, you can use [File.traverse(Map, Closure)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse(java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []
def dir = new File("source")

dir.traverse(type: FileType.FILES, nameFilter: ~/.*\.html/) { list << it }

list.each {
  println it.path
}
```

In the example above, I used the `nameFilter` option to specify a regular expression to filter the file name by. You can about the other available options in the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse(java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need all file one by one like array list element

Comment: What do you mean by *I need specific files from list*?